# How to translate Facebook pages (including posts)? Chrome's built-in feature does not work

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, google, facebook

Is there a way to translate Facebook pages on Chrome/any other browser?

I'm not talking about the Facebook built-in Bing translation on individual posts, but the entire page. Things I tried that didn't work:

- Using Chrome's built-in Google Translate
- Right-clicking and selecting "Translate to English"
- Changed the entire site into Chinese/another language and it also did not work:

[image: Screenshot of a Facebook page in Chinese that Google Translate says is in English]

This seems to only be a problem with Facebook. Is there a program/extension that can translate this without me having to individually copy and paste each page?